# I want to remove part of the name from a url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Hi Friends I Want to create new page as per country name dynamically i create them as per query and links also working but i got a problem i want to remove page name from url where am put all this code

now Links Are Like

https://www.example.com/result/canada....................After use Htaccess This Url Is Working Fine
orignal Url is (https://www.example.com/result.php?canada)
 But
I Want This Url Like

https://www.example.com/canada

Please Tell Me The Right Way To Do with Htaccess

My Site Is in Core Php. Not In Wordpress

Comment: can you show us your .htaccess?

Comment: Just made a quick grammar and formatting pass to clarify what I believe is trying to be done here. Also dropped in some domain-specific vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/?$ /result/$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: First of all Thanx For your help, i trying to use as per your answer but its not working....plz give an other solution if is there

Comment: "not working" has never helped anyone anywhere in any situation. You need to be specific. What does that mean? What happens? A wrong rewriting? Nothing at all? An error message? Does the universe implode?